# Python Turtle program dying instantly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My caterpillar gets shown in one frame and then the screen says "Game Over". Please tell me why this is happening. The screen is supposed to say "Game Over" when the caterpillar goes off screen, but it does it immediately after you start. My code:

```
import random
import turtle as t

t.bgcolor('yellow')

caterpillar = t.Turtle()
caterpillar.shape('square')
caterpillar.color('red')
caterpillar.speed(0)
caterpillar.penup()
caterpillar.hideturtle()

leaf = t.Turtle()
leaf_shape = ((0, 0), (14, 2), (18, 6), (20, 20), (6, 18), (2, 14))
t.register_shape('leaf', leaf_shape)
leaf.shape('leaf')
leaf.color('green')
leaf.penup()
leaf.hideturtle()
leaf.speed(0)

game_started = False
text_turtle = t.Turtle()
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align='center', font=('Arial', 16, 
'bold'))
text_turtle.hideturtle

score_turtle = t.Turtle()
score_turtle.hideturtle()
score_turtle.speed(0)

def outside_window():
    left_wall = -t.window_width() / 2
    right_wall = t.window_width() / 2
    top_wall = t.window_height() / 2
    bottom_wall = -t.window_height() / 2
    (x, y) = caterpillar.pos()
    outside = \
            x< left_wall or \
            x> right_wall or \
            y< bottom_wall or \
            y> top_wall
    return outside

def game_over():
    caterpillar.color('yellow')
    leaf.color('yellow')
    t.penup()
    t.hideturtle()
    t.write('GAME OVER!', align='center', font=('Arial', 30, 'normal'))

def display_score(current_score):
    score_turtle.clear()
    score_turtle.penup()
    x = (t.window_width() / 2) - 50
    y = (t.window_height() / 2) - 50
    score_turtle.setpos(x, y)
    score_turtle.write(str(current_score), align='right', font=('Arial', 40, 
'bold))

def place_leaf():
    leaf.ht()
    leaf.setx(random.randint(-200, 200))
    leaf.sety(random.randint(-200, 200))
    leaf.st()

def start_game():
    global game_started
    if game_started:
        return
    game_started = True

    score = 0
    text_turtle.clear()

    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()
    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()

    while True:
        caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)
        if caterpillar.distance(leaf) < 20:
            place_leaf()
            caterpillar_length = caterpillar_length + 1
            caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
            caterpillar_speed = caterpillar_speed + 1
            score = score + 10
            display_score()
        if outside_window:
            game_over()
            break

def move_up():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 0 or caterpillar.heading() == 180:
        caterpillar.setheading(90)

def move_down():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 0 or caterpillar.heading() == 180:
        caterpillar.setheading(270)

def move_left():
   if caterpillar.heading() == 90 or caterpillar.heading() == 270:
        caterpillar.setheading(180)

def move_right():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 90 or caterpillar.heading() == 270:
        caterpillar.setheading(0)
t.onkey(start_game, 'space')
t.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
t.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
t.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
t.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
t.listen()
t.mainloop()
```

Please help me spot the things that are wrong. This code is from the book "Coding Projects in Python". I can't find out why it dies.  I retyped the code but then the caterpillar didn't move! I found some errors but then it does the 1 frame and game over thing! If you find some logic errors, please tell me. I'm a noob at Python.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE] and add your code so we can help your.

Answer (score 0):

What I see are lots of little editing errors:

```
text_turtle.hideturtle -> text_turtle.hideturtle()

font=('Arial', 40, 'bold) -> font=('Arial', 40, 'bold')

display_score() -> display_score(score)
```

And this one in particular that causes your program to quickly exit:

```
if outside_window: -> if outside_window():
```

Below is my rework of your code to fix the above problems plus some style changes to your code:

```
import random
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('yellow')

caterpillar = Turtle('square', visible=False)
caterpillar.color('red')
caterpillar.speed('fastest')
caterpillar.penup()

leaf_shape = ((0, 0), (14, 2), (18, 6), (20, 20), (6, 18), (2, 14))
screen.register_shape('leaf', leaf_shape)

leaf = Turtle('leaf', visible=False)
leaf.color('green')
leaf.speed('fastest')
leaf.penup()

game_started = False
text_turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
text_turtle.write('Press SPACE to start', align='center', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))

score_turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
score_turtle.speed('fastest')
score_turtle.penup()
x = (screen.window_width() / 2) - 50
y = (screen.window_height() / 2) - 50
score_turtle.setpos(x, y)
score_turtle.write(0, align='right', font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'))

def outside_window():
    left_wall = -screen.window_width() / 2
    right_wall = screen.window_width() / 2
    top_wall = screen.window_height() / 2
    bottom_wall = -screen.window_height() / 2

    x, y = caterpillar.pos()

    outside = \
        x < left_wall or \
        x > right_wall or \
        y < bottom_wall or \
        y > top_wall

    return outside

def game_over():
    caterpillar.color('yellow')
    leaf.color('yellow')
    text_turtle.write('GAME OVER!', align='center', font=('Arial', 30, 'normal'))

def display_score(current_score):
    score_turtle.undo()  # erase previous score
    score_turtle.write(current_score, align='right', font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'))

def place_leaf():
    leaf.hideturtle()
    leaf.setx(random.randint(-200, 200))
    leaf.sety(random.randint(-200, 200))
    leaf.showturtle()

def start_game():
    global game_started

    if game_started:
        return
    game_started = True

    score = 0
    text_turtle.clear()

    caterpillar_speed = 2
    caterpillar_length = 3
    caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
    caterpillar.showturtle()
    display_score(score)
    place_leaf()

    while True:
        caterpillar.forward(caterpillar_speed)

        if caterpillar.distance(leaf) < 20:
            place_leaf()
            caterpillar_length += 1
            caterpillar.shapesize(1, caterpillar_length, 1)
            caterpillar_speed += 1
            score += 10
            display_score(score)

        if outside_window():
            game_over()
            break

def move_up():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 0 or caterpillar.heading() == 180:
        caterpillar.setheading(90)

def move_down():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 0 or caterpillar.heading() == 180:
        caterpillar.setheading(270)

def move_left():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 90 or caterpillar.heading() == 270:
        caterpillar.setheading(180)

def move_right():
    if caterpillar.heading() == 90 or caterpillar.heading() == 270:
        caterpillar.setheading(0)

screen.onkey(start_game, 'space')
screen.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

It's fun to play!

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it... LOL this was from awhile ago and I was a COMPLETE noob at Python. Thanks alot though!